# finding in which month most clients created their account in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, count, match, document

I created a collection called clients and inserted `6` clients documents
each document in the collection looks like that only with different values:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b520bbadd4017fadf37ebf9"),
    "name" : "ron",
    "last" : "omer",
    "age" : "40",
    "enter" : {
            "year" : "2018",
            "month" : "07",
            "day" : "12"
    },
    "leave" : {
            "year" : "2018",
            "month" : "09",
            "day" : "12"
    },
    "CId" : "4"
}
```

How can I show month in which the most clients joined?
I tried using match and count but just cant make it to work.

```
db.clients.aggregate([{$match:{"enter.year":$not{null}},{$group:{_id:null,count:{$sum:1}}}]);
```

But its not really close to working.

Answer (score 0):

ok, found the way.

```
db.clients.aggregate([{$sortByCount:"$enter.month"}]);
```

results:

```
{ "_id" : "07", "count" : 5 }
{ "_id" : "05", "count" : 1 }
```